# Double Past Tense?

Tags: past-tense

Can you please tell me which one of these sentences is correct, and why? Thanks!

> Lastly, my experience as a teaching assistant helped me throughout the course as I shared what I did to make my students succeed in the courses that I **helped teach**.

versus

> Lastly, my experience as a teaching assistant helped me throughout the course as I shared what I did to make my students succeed in the courses that I **helped taught**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first is grammatical.

The reason might be easier to understand if you substitute another verb for ‘helped’. If the sentence had been ‘. . . what I did to make my students succeed in the courses that I **wanted to teach**’, then it’s clear that the finite verb ‘wanted’ is followed by the infinitive ‘to teach’. The use of ‘help’ is a special case, because it is one of the few lexical verbs that can be followed by the bare infinitive, that is, the infinitive without the particle ‘to’.

Answer (score 1):

You want the first version

http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive

> **Verbs followed by to + infinitive**
>
> Verbs of thinking and feeling:
>
> choose,
>   decide,
>   expect,
>   forget,
>   hate,
>   hope,
>   intend,
>   learn,
>   like,
>   love,
>   mean,
>   plan,
>   prefer,
>   remember,
>   would like,
>   would love,
>
> Verbs of saying:
>   agree,
>   promise,
>   refuse,
>
> Other common verbs are:
>   arrange,
>   attempt,
>   fail,
>   help,
>   manage,
>   tend,
>   try,
>   want

In your case you left out the "to", which is allowed for some of the above

Please also visit http://ell.stackexchange.com